# How can i do Physics Joint of bodies in cocos2d-x 3.3?

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

How can i Joint these two(Car and Wheel)as a single Physics body in a cocos2d-x 3.3?
    how to add this Joint body into Physics world??

```
Sprite *car=Sprite::create("abc.png");
car->setPosition(100,400);
car->setScale(1.5, 1.5);
this->addChild(car);
PhysicsBody *car_body=PhysicsBody::create();
car->setPhysicsBody(car_body);
car_body->setGravityEnable(false);

Sprite *wheel=Sprite::create("abc.png");
wheel->setPosition(40,350);
this->addChild(wheel);

PhysicsBody *wheel_bd=PhysicsBody::create(); 
wheel_bd=PhysicsBody::createCircle(69.0/64.0);
wheel->setPhysicsBody(wheel_bd);
wheel_bd->setGravityEnable(false);
PhysicsJoint *co =PhysicsJointGroove::construct(wheel->getPhysicsBody(),
car->getPhysicsBody(),Vec2(80,250),Vec2(160,250),Vec2(1.0,1.0));
scene->getPhysicsWorld()->addJoint(co); //this line creating error into my code.
```

Comment: because world is null and you have to pass world into this layer via scene

Comment: Thank you bro...I'm new in PhysicsPrograming.how can i pass world into layer?       Is that above bodies Joint correct?

Answer (score 0):

I Suspect this Error is Due to your car_body Not having any Shape, Try adding a Shape to ur car_body, DO Something like this
Edit:-

```
        Sprite *car=Sprite::create("abc.png");
        car->setPosition(100,400);
        car->setScale(1.5, 1.5);

        PhysicsBody *car_Body = PhysicsBody::create();
        car_Body->addShape(PhysicsShapeBox::create(car->getBoundingBox().size);
        car_Body->setGravityEnable(false);
        car->setPhysicsBody(car_body);
        this->addChild(car);
```

In above code your car Physics Body will have a Bounding Box of your Sprite 
Also u are a little waste full here:-

```
         PhysicsBody *wheel_bd = PhysicsBody::create(); 
         wheel_bd=PhysicsBody::createCircle(69.0/64.0);
```

u should do something like this:-

```
         PhysicsBody *wheel_bd = PhysicsBody::create();
         wheel_bd ->addShape(PhysicsShapeCircle::create(69.0/64.0));
```

Comment: Yes..you are right there...But i having issue that how can i assign image to Wheel and Car??

Comment: same way u did above in your code, it will work, what i gave u is the proper way to create Physics Body using Integrated Physics, rest of ur code looks fine to me

Comment: ok...how can i joint these three Physics body (wheel1,wheel2 and Car_body) in cocos2d-x v3.3rc0?

Comment: i would do something like Creating a Custom Car Class by extending CCSprite and inside that class i would add three bodies along with their respective Sprites(Car_body, Car_hood, car_cabinet), and Position them accordingly, this will give me a Nice car Shape, and also i can modify my car as i wish by adding more components to it, I will also run a Update method which will update all car childs(hood, cabinets etc) with cars main body.